# Rendering issue: light artifacts [EEVEE Blender 2.81A]

Tags: rendering, light, eevee-render-engine, artifacts

I am trying to render an animation scene with a volumetric effect in EEVEE.

As shown below, some frames contain light artifacts in form of white spots with a touch of RGB on the sides. They seem to appear in random places throughout all 950 frames, though only in rendering, never in viewport. I tried to increase the sampling of the volumetric effect and final rendering, but it had no impact.

Does anyone know what might cause this issue and how to solve this problem? I'll be very grateful for any guidance.

**EDIT:** added .blend file under http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52772

[image]

Comment: can you check if any post effects are causing this like bloom intensity or dof. maybe an objet you forgot to delete, a vertex or particle system ?
seems weird indeed

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tried to change the bloom intensity, but it only made the spots appear on different frames. the outcome is irreplicable though, even if I leave the settings as they are. all objects and normals are as they should be :(

Comment: no probs, maybe try a separate test scene and replace the light, camera and other things you added to see which is causing this.

Comment: Please do not add "solved" as part of the title. Mark the answer as accepted instead (https://i.stack.imgur.com/qBQh7.png). Please take the [tour] to understand how the site works. Read also: [what does it mean when an answer is accepted?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was solved by changing the value of Light Treshold from 0.1 to 1.0 (under render -> shadows)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, but was only able to rid my renders of the rgb artifacts by changing the "Volumetric Lighting" tab's Light Clamping from 0.00 to a higher value just like the light threshold within the "Shadows" tab fixed yours.