# Where are these 'flares' coming from? New User

Tags: camera, light, eevee-render-engine, lighting

[image: Multicoloured flares]

I'm getting these 'flares', for lack of a better word, appearing all over my camera viewport and rendered animation. They come in just about every colour you can imagine and I can't for the life of me figure out what's generating them. Using Eevee if that helps.

If anyone has any suggestions then help would be greatly appreciated! I'm quite new to Blender and am working through the terminology.

As I'm not sure where they're coming from I'm not really sure what information to include in this post so I'm sorry if it's:
a) a super simple answer or
b) an incredibly vague problem

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: Would you mind uploading the blendfile to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/? It's kinda hard to find the issue from the image alone

Comment: @haarigertroll
Thanks for replying! Here's the link:
[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2nBnAQ4q" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2nBnAQ4q/)

Last night I changed the tile size from 2px to 4px in the volumetrics for a cube that the scene sits in and haven't checked to see if that changed anything yet this morning

Comment: BUG report https://developer.blender.org/T77202 Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/167395 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/163706 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/192735